# Truncated Backproapgation Through Time Pytorch and Lightning

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, backpropagation, pytorch-lightning

I'm tring to implement TBPTT using Pytorch and Pytorch Lightning.
In my training procedure I feed batched sequences of shape (4, 500, 20).
In this setting I have 4 sequences of length 500 with 20 features.
I try to use them with an LSTM but it struggles to learn something out of them so I have tried to implement TBPTT using the following:

```
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = batch                
    y = y.squeeze()  
    opt = self.optimizers()

    #reset gradients
    opt.zero_grad()

    #compute subsequences (4, 500, 20 ) --> (40, 50, 20)
    sub_sequences = self.get_sub_seq(x)

    output, hidden = self(sub_sequences)
    loss = nn.functional.cross_entropy(output, y)

    self.manual_backward(loss)
    opt.step()

    #detatch the hidden for the subsequences computed
    hidden.detatch()

    return loss
```

Where the function get_sub_seq is:

```
def get_sub_seq(self, x):
    batch_size, seq_len, in_size = x.size()

    if seq_len % self.sub_seq_len != 0:
        raise ValueError("Sub sequence length not compatible with sequence length.")
    
    n_sub_seq = seq_len / self.sub_seq_len
    return x.view(-1, self.sub_seq_len, in_size)
```

What I'm doing is reshaping the sequences from (4, 500, 20) to (40, 50, 20) but then I don't really now how to process them.
I have tried to search for some implementation of TBPTT but I don't have found anything useful.

Could you help me understand if my code is correct and if it actually implements TBPTT or, if not, what kind of changes I have to do to make it work correctly?